# adding up numerical values ​in the table (sum)

Tags: javascript, html

- I have number inputs
- number around 30
- I need to sum them all to one field
- what I have is below

**View:**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="days_tpu" type="number" id="sth_1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="days_tpu" type="number" id="sth_2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="days_tpu" type="number" id="sth_3"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

    // field in which it will add up
    <tfoot>
    <th><input id="id_days_tpu" type="time" type="text"></th>

    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**I tried:**

- I try to take all inputs.
- and count by length
- and sum them

but, it doesn't work

**Javascript:**

```
const days_tpu_s = [...document.getElementsByClassName("days_tpu")];

//or

const table = document.querySelector('table');


table.sumInputs = function () {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('days_tpu'),
        result = document.getElementById('sum_id_days_tpu'),
        sum = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var ip = inputs[i];

        if (ip.name && ip.name.indexOf("total") < 0) {
            sum += parseInt(ip.value) || 0;
        }

    }

    result.value = sum;
}
 sumInputs();
```

anyone have a good idea?

Comment: Try changing `table.sumInputs` to be a new variable.

Comment: Your input type is *time*, do you want to sum the *time* value?

Comment: @Mamun sorry, number, I corrected

Comment: @krolPodGora, I have posted my answer, please check:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get all the input value the use [**Array.prototype.reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to sum them.

**Demo:**

```js
const days_tpu_s = [...document.getElementsByClassName("days_tpu")];
function sumInputs() {
  var sum = days_tpu_s.map(i => Number(i.value)).reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0);
  document.getElementById('id_days_tpu').value = sum;
}
days_tpu_s.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('input', sumInputs);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><input class="days_tpu" type="number" id="sth_1"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input class="days_tpu" type="number" id="sth_2"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input class="days_tpu" type="number" id="sth_3"></td></tr>
  </tbody>

  // field in which it will add up
  <tfoot>
    <th><input id="id_days_tpu" type="text"></th>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```